# 'this' in Component of Typescript vs ES5 in Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ecmascript-5

So I've been trying to work through converting my Angular2 app from Typescript to ES5 and have been trying to make both of them run similarly. The problem that I'm having is getting the `this.people` to update in the ES5 version.

When I console.log `this` in the **constructor** versus in my **searchFor** method, I get the scoping of the class versus the window's scope. When I console.log `this` in my Typescript version, it stays within the SearchComponent and is the same in both.

**Typescript Version:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {PersonService} from './person-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  properties: ['searchTerm'],
  templateUrl: `search.html`,
})

export class SearchComponent {
  searchTerm:string;
  searchPrefix:string;
  people:Person[];

  constructor(private _personService:PersonService) {
    this.searchTerm   = '';
    this.searchPrefix = "";
    this.people       = [];
    this.predicate    = 'last';
  }

  searchFor(term) {
    if (term.length < 2)
      this.people = [];
    else {
      this._personService.getUsers(term)
        .then((people)=> {
          this.people = people;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

**ES5 Version**

```
(function(app) {
  app.SearchComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'search',
      properties: ['searchTerm'],
      templateUrl: 'search.html',
      providers: [app.PersonService]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: [app.PersonService, ng.router.Router,
        function(_personService, _router) {
          this.searchTerm = '';
          this.searchPrefix = "";
          this.people = [];
          this._personService = _personService;
          this._router = _router;
        }
      ],
      searchFor(term){
        if (term.length < 2)
          this.people = [];
        else {
          this._personService.getUsers(term)
            .then(function(people) {
              //Problem is with the 'this' below:
              this.people = people;
            });
        }
      }
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

I've had some success in making the components and services work but I'm a bit stumped on `this`, *ha*. Any help or corrections with the issue would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code to be:

```
 this._personService.getUsers(term)
        .then(function(people) {
          //Problem is with the 'this' below:
          this.people = people;
        }.bind(this));
```

(The context of this is wrong. In ES6 you have arrow function which solve this problem)

Comment: That works, thanks a whole bunch! Guess I need to do more review with the concept of`this` and scoping.

Comment: In TypeScript arrow functions exist so in this case it's more readable to use an arrow function than `.bind`